# Adding a Check Box to a Custom Ribbon in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, excel-365

I need help in adding a checkbox in my custom Excel ribbon that will allow me to run a certain function if it's clicked. I was able to get the checkbox to appear, but it does nothing when clicked. I need something similar to this example provided , but it needs to work on the latest version of Excel 365. https://spreadsheetgurucourses.com/checkbox-control/#

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonLoaded_myAddin" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyCoolAddin" label="My Cool Addin">
        <group id="GroupA" label="Checkbox Example">
          <checkBox
            id="Checkbox01"
            label="Display Gridlines"
            getPressed="checkbox01_startup"
            onAction="checkbox01_clicked"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Have you implemented the VBA Code as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the callbacks in VBA ... for the above RibbonXML you need these three in a standard Module:

```
Sub RibbonLoaded_myAddin(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
End Sub

Sub checkbox01_startup(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
End Sub

Sub checkbox01_clicked(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
    If pressed Then
        MsgBox "I'm checked"
    Else
        MsgBox "I'm cleared"
    End If
End Sub
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might not need the first two. Then add code into `checkbox01_clicked` for what you want to happen when the checkbox is checked / cleared.